# Refresh Excel PowerQuery Table before import at ftp via PHP

Tags: php, excel, powerquery

Hello i try to set up automate cron import to prestashop using excel power query table. The problem is i have table edited at my computer fetching data from external source. I need to write a script in PHP that will refresh the xlsx file before sending it to import php.

Now the steps are, Open Excel, Press Refresh All, Save, Upload to FTP, Run Import.
I want to automate these steps for PHP.

Thank you.

Comment: What's the purpose of passing those data in Excel ?
If you have the data in a external source you can read them directly with PHP, process them and import them in Prestashop through the same script or using webservices.

Comment: because i am formatting the external data using power query to be importable format for my prestashop module, problem is just to refresh excel query using php